# Backblaze restore and verify not working (duplicity)

Tags: backup, duplicity

I have been using Duplicity to backup my home dir to Backblaze. Creating new backups appears to be working, but when I try to either `restore` or `verify` files, I'm getting the following error:

```
Attempt of get Nr. 1 failed. B2ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='f004.backblazeb2.com', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /file/jf-laptop-backup/duplicity-full.20220218T202356Z.vol275.difftar.gpg 
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 
0x7f7a0220cb50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))
```

I was hoping that this was a temporary problem on their end, but I've been getting it over the past two days.

Comment: It's probably a issue at your end. The error is that name resolutions doesn't work. Does `nslookup f004.backblazeb2.com` return an answer?

Comment: It doesn't - but `nslookup backblazeb2.com` does work.

Comment: Try a different DNS server, such as 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1. It's a issue with your DNS service.

Comment: I changed my DNS to 1.1.1.1, but I'm still getting the same problem. Indeed, when I run `nslookup f004.backblazeb2.com 1.1.1.1` or `nslookup f004.backblazeb2.com 8.8.4.4` I also get timeouts.

Is it possible that this is an ISP problem? I'm on a university network

Comment: It may very well be. I would suggest using the NS provided by your network in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this was caused by a firewall at work; I had to ask to have backblaze whitelisted.